# How to distribute selected listitem through a table (days of week)

Tags: usability, layout, tables, drag-n-drop

What 's the best way to do the following :

I want to distribute my employees among the specific periods in the week

My current UI is like that 
[image]

on The right side :

The list box of employees

and the left side 7 days of the selected week according to the periods.
when the user click on the slot of the Grid it brings the selected employee to the clicked slot .

I there a more wise UI to this problem .

Comment: It looks to me, like you have one row per employee, and one column per day, right? How many employees are we talking about here? Are there restraints about how many employees you need on a day, or how many days you may use a specific employee?

Comment: @André:the number of employees is variant ..the number of employees for each cell (period) about 5.

Comment: Ok, so I interpreted it wrong. The rows do not represent employees, they represent weeks. The screen you show us represents four weeks worth of schedule. The number of employees is relevant, because not all possible solutions scale to all numbers of items. So, are we talking 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, or even more employees? This is not about absolute numbers, but orders of magnitude.

Comment: @André :The list box in each cell can hold between 5-10 employee names which comes from the list box (employees) in the right side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, based on what I understand of the problem now, I'd consider something like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flDw3U.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

This would be the design per cell in your planning grid. The idea is to show the employees working that day directly in the cell, and you can add new employees to the list from a little popup that appears if you click the + icon. Depending on your needs (and like Igor-G already suggested), you could also allow other ways to add persons, for instance by somehow activating an employee from your side list, and then clicking every cell he needs to be added to. That would make it much faster to add a single employee to multiple days. I'd also consider the option to copy a previous schedule into a new week, so you don't have to go from scratch every time. Normally, schedules tend to be fairly regular with some exceptions here and there.

Answer (score 1):

There are few different ways you could takle this problem:

1. Drag and drop (drag the employee to the day you want them to work)
2. In Days boxes have drop-down with employee names
3. Select an employee and then click on all days/slots that you want them to work so you dont have to select the employee multiple times
4. Select the days/slots and then select an employee that you want them to work

So there are multiple solutions to this problem, you need to decide what will work best for you. Also will it be used on mobile devices, phones or tablets, or only on computers.